# How I can copy files from one remote workspace to master machine in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, copy, master-slave

I have created one jenkins pipeline in which I am running 4 jobs on four slave machine, it creates four workspaces on all 4 slave machines ,once the execution will be completed ,I want to copy some files from the slave workspaces to master workspace or master machine .
Please help me to figure out the solution for the same.

Comment: Check out the [archiveArtifacts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/core/#archiveartifacts-archive-the-artifacts) step, it will store the flies on the server and make them available in the build page.

Comment: If you build actual sub-jobs (separate projects), then you will have to use the `archiveArtifacts` as mentioned above. If you have a single pipeline with four distinct `node {... }` blocks, then you can use the `stash/unstash`  commands https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SSH Pipeline steps](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-steps/) and use the command sshGet.
Here's the code:
`sshGet remote: remote, from: "${yourSlaveFilePath}", into: "${yourJenkinsworkspaceFileName}"`

---